# CW answers considered harmful?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, accepted-answer

*Not really a discussion, more of a cautionary tale:*

I sometimes write answers that are basically just compilations of facts that have already been noticed in comments to the question, but which I think add up to a resolution of the problem. Usually I mark these answers as CW, because I don't think my essentially clerical contribution warrants me getting reputation from upvotes.

Recently I noticed that when the OP accepted [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186730/calculate-x-slower-faster/186738#186738) (which was CW because originally it was only one line), the OP did not receive the usual +2 rep for accepting an answer.

It appears to be [by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35928/2-on-accepting-answers-something-is-wrong-with-my-account-on-so) that accepting a CW answer does not gain the OP +2, but it was certainly not my intention to penalize the OP in that way when I CW-ed my answer.

In the future I think I will just write ordinary answers and soak up the unearned rep gain myself.

Comment: There is also a meta.SO thread on this: [Why doesn't accepting a CW answer for a not CW question give reputation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126381/why-doesnt-accepting-a-cw-answer-for-a-not-cw-question-give-reputation) But I did not find any explanation there, either.

Comment: Perhaps I am mistaken, but my impression is that relatively few people actually care about the +2 rep for accepting answers--it's essentially a trivial amount of reputation. But I agree that it makes no sense to penalize the OP for accepting a CW answer over other, non-CW answers.

Comment: Even secretaries get paid :-) Seriously, the ideas should be put into an answer, and compiling comments deserves some reward.

Comment: Agreeing with robjohn. I don't think your rep gain is unearned, but if you are uncomfortable with it, you could always offer it as a bounty on some question you'd like to see answered.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: My _conscience_ is perfectly comfortable with receiving the points. It's my _vanity_ that worries about giving the impression that I'm leeching on others' work. Nothing to see here, move along. :-)